# Slack API Event Subscription to trigger Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, slack-api

### Goal

I would like Slack to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function.

Example: A user sends a Slack message, and Firebase Cloud Functions writes part of the message to the Firebase Database.

Tools: Slack API \ Event Subscription, googleapis, nodejs, etc.

### Issue

The Slack documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/events-api#prepare) describes the challenge response requirement.

> Once you receive the event, respond in plaintext with the challenge
>   attribute value.

However, I'm not sure how to let Firebase know the Slack request is authorized. An HTTP request to Firebase Cloud Functions must include a **Firebase ID**. I've let googleapis do the work of setting up the Firebase ID, and I don't see a way to alter Slack's initial verification request (if I had an ID to provide)

What's the best way to trigger Firebase with the Slack API?

Comment: I would suggest an adapter between Slack and Firebase to ensure requests are converted correctly between the two platforms.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken can you point me to an example of this type of adapter? Is this something like IFTTT?

Comment: Possibly, but since this is a developer forum I meant developing and deploying your own adapter

Comment: @ErikKalkoken yes, I would like to stay within Google's services, and possibly write my own "adapter". An example would help me see how this is accomplished. Maybe a stand-alone firebase project that does this "adapting" or a separate Google Cloud Function could "adapt". Looking for something more than the word "adapt". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting Slack to verify the Firebase URL is pretty easy.

### Solution

*Google Firebase Cloud Function*

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloSlack = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  if (request) {
    response.status(200).send(request.body);
  } else {
    console.log("Request Error...");
    throw response.status(500);
  }
});
```

### Steps

1. Deploy your Firebase Cloud Function
2. Goto https://api.slack.com/apps
3. Your App > Event Subscriptions > Enable Events
4. Turn on Events
5. Enter your Firebase Cloud Functions URL

### tl;dr

Slack instructions:

> We’ll send HTTP POST requests to [your] URL when events occur. As soon
>   as you enter a URL, we’ll send a request with a challenge parameter,
>   and your endpoint must respond with the challenge value.

Cloud Function URL:

`https://firebase-slack-adaptor.cloudfunctions.net/helloSlack`

To meet the verification challenge, enter your Firebase Cloud Functions URL (example above) in Slack's Request URL field.

Your Firebase Cloud Function should return the `body` of the Slack request. Slack finds what it needs in `request.body` and should verify your URL.